# Event Handler inquiries Java - How to use a button to go to a new scene and how to display text input from text fields on console?

Tags: java, javafx

Assignment description from teacher:

> Create an application that has a button that has “Enter your info.”  When clicked it will present a dialog that has labels and text boxes that allow the user to enter their name, email, and phone number.  The dialog will have buttons OK and Cancel.
>
> When the user clicks Cancel, the dialog will go away without doing anything else.

I've tried talking to my teacher about my questions but he either doesn't seem to really understand my problem or wants me to somehow figure it out, but I've genuinely tried most of what I can think.

So this is a simple JavaFX GUI, it's supposed to start with a button, that when pressed will send you to a new window that has 3x text fields, an OK and a CANCEL button. We are supposed to have the OK button print out the text entered into the text fields onto the console, the CANCEL button should clear all inputs and close the program.

My issues are with how to get the right info into my event handlers. How I did this code was in two separate projects, first one is just a simple GUI with a button that when pressed, should send me to the screen with text fields and two buttons, OK and Cancel but I don't fully grasp how to send it over to that stage, it might be an issue with having done the two windows completely separately but I've tried to but them together with no luck.

The second issue is when I'm in the window that has allows you to enter inputs and OK and Cancel button is how can I extract the text entered into the textfields in the GUI to display on the console.

This is my code for each of the windows, remember they are completely separate projects as I was trying to turn this in as complete as I could before the deadline so I split it up. Hopefully it's understandable and questions makes sense.

CODE FOR FIRST WINDOW - [GUI SCREENSHOT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5RzN.png)

```
public class Main extends Application {
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    // Enter info button and handler set up
    Button infoInput = new Button("Enter your info");
    NextStageSwap switchStage = new NextStageSwap();
    infoInput.setOnAction(switchStage);

    // Stack pane setup
    StackPane pane = new StackPane();
    pane.getChildren().addAll(infoInput);

    // New scene and display stage

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Information Gather");
    primaryStage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}

class NextStageSwap implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
    // This handlers should sent me to the window where you can enter info 
    //into text field and has the OK and CANCEL buttons
}
}
```

CODE FOR SECOND WINDOW - [GUI SCREENSHOT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGPSd.png)

```
public class InfoInputStage extends Application {

public void start(Stage secondaryStage) {

    // Grid Pane setup
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    grid.setVgap(8);
    grid.setHgap(10);

    // Labels and Inputs
    Label nameLabel = new Label("Name:");
    GridPane.setConstraints(nameLabel, 0, 0);

    TextField nameInput = new TextField("");
    GridPane.setConstraints(nameInput, 1, 0);

    Label emailLabel = new Label("Email:");
    GridPane.setConstraints(emailLabel, 0, 1);

    TextField emailInput = new TextField("");
    GridPane.setConstraints(emailInput, 1, 1);

    Label phoneLabel = new Label("Phone Number:");
    GridPane.setConstraints(phoneLabel, 0, 2);

    TextField phoneInput = new TextField("");
    GridPane.setConstraints(phoneInput, 1, 2);

    // OK and Cancel buttons with hanlders set up
    Button okBtn = new Button("Ok");
    GridPane.setConstraints(okBtn, 0, 3);
    DisplayInfoClass displayInfo = new DisplayInfoClass();
    okBtn.setOnAction(displayInfo);
    Button cancelBtn = new Button("Cancel");
    GridPane.setConstraints(cancelBtn, 1, 3);
    ClearInfoClass clearInfo = new ClearInfoClass();
    cancelBtn.setOnAction(clearInfo);

    // Insert shit onto grid
    grid.getChildren().addAll(nameLabel, nameInput, emailLabel, emailInput, phoneLabel, phoneInput, okBtn,
            cancelBtn);

    // New Scene and display stage
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(grid, 400, 400);
    secondaryStage.setScene(scene2);
    secondaryStage.setTitle("Info input stage");
    secondaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}

class DisplayInfoClass implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>  {

public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
    //This is the handler for the OK button, I want to print the texts from    the text fields onto the console when pressed
}
}

class ClearInfoClass implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
    //This is the handler for the CANCEL button, I want it to clear the text fields and close the program.      
}
}
```

Comment: You only need one Application, you won't get it to work at all with two applications.

Comment: It's suspicious how often your teacher uses the term dialog... Maybe you should use this class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) or implement something similar yourself (which could easily be achieved using `Stage.showAndWait()`). Also do not use `Application`s for every part of the GUI, since only one of them can be launched; move the logic of the `start` method to some more convenient place...

Comment: A great place to start: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/